# reusableforms edit email template

Tags: php, forms, email

I have implemented reusableforms on my site everything is working but i would like to add some styling to the email which is received.

handler.php reads from FormHandler.php, how would I get a html email template to be used when the form is posted and email to me? currently the message is being posted but no template is being used. what needs editing

handler.php

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler();

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('secretkey');


$pp->useMailTemplate(__DIR__.'/email.html')
->sendEmailTo('mail@domain.com'); // ← Your email here


echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

FormHandler.php

```
    <?php
namespace FormGuide\Handlx;
use FormGuide\PHPFormValidator\FormValidator;
use PHPMailer;
use FormGuide\Handlx\Microtemplate;
use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;

/**
 * FormHandler
 *  A wrapper class that handles common form handling tasks
 *      - handles Form validations using PHPFormValidator class
 *      - sends email using PHPMailer
 *      - can handle captcha validation
 *      - can handle file uploads and attaching the upload to email
 *
 *  ==== Sample usage ====
 *   $fh = FormHandler::create()->validate(function($validator)
 *          {
 *              $validator->fields(['name','email'])
 *                        ->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
 *              $validator->field('email')->isEmail();
 *
 *           })->useMailTemplate(__DIR__.'/templ/email.php')
 *           ->sendEmailTo('you@website.com');
 *
 *   $fh->process($_POST);
 */
class FormHandler
{
    private $emails;
    public $validator;
    private $mailer;
    private $mail_template;
    private $captcha;
    private $attachments;
    private $recaptcha;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = array();
        $this->validator = FormValidator::create();
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail_template='/../email.html';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Trade Print Order Form";

        $host = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']:'localhost';
        $from_email ='forms@'.$host;
        $this->mailer->setFrom($from_email,'Trade Print Order',false);

        $this->captcha = false;

        $this->attachments = [];

        $this->recaptcha =null;


    }

    /**
     * sendEmailTo: add a recipient email address
     * @param  string/array $email_s one or more emails. If more than one emails, pass the emails as array
     * @return The form handler object itself so that the methods can be chained
     */
    public function sendEmailTo($email_s)
    {
        if(is_array($email_s))
        {
            $this->emails =array_merge($this->emails, $email_s);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->emails[] = $email_s;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function useMailTemplate($templ_path)
    {
        $this->mail_template = $templ_path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [attachFiles find the file uplods and attach to the email]
     * @param  array $fields The array of field names
      */
    public function attachFiles($fields)
    {
        $this->attachments = array_merge($this->attachments, $fields);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipients()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    /**
     * [validate add Validations. This function takes a call back function which receives the PHPFormValidator object]
     * @param  function $validator_fn The funtion gets a validator parameter using which, you can add validations
     */
    public function validate($validator_fn)
    {
        $validator_fn($this->validator);
        return $this;
    }

    public function requireReCaptcha($config_fn=null)
    {
        $this->recaptcha = new ReCaptchaValidator();
        $this->recaptcha->enable(true);
        if($config_fn)
        {
            $config_fn($this->recaptcha);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getReCaptcha()
    {
        return $this->recaptcha;
    }

    public function requireCaptcha($enable=true)
    {
        $this->captcha = $enable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    public function configMailer($mailconfig_fn)
    {
        $mailconfig_fn($this->mailer);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMailer()
    {
        return $this->mailer;
    }

    public static function create()
    {
        return new FormHandler();
    }

    public function process($post_data)
    {
        if($this->captcha === true)
        {
            $res = $this->validate_captcha($post_data);
            if($res !== true)
            {
                return $res;
            }
        }
        if($this->recaptcha !== null &&
           $this->recaptcha->isEnabled())
        {
            if($this->recaptcha->validate() !== true)
            {
                return json_encode([
                'result'=>'recaptcha_validation_failed',
                'errors'=>['captcha'=>'ReCaptcha Validation Failed.']
                ]);
            }
        }

        $this->validator->test($post_data);

        //if(false == $this->validator->test($post_data))
        if($this->validator->hasErrors())
        {
            return json_encode([
                'result'=>'validation_failed',
                'errors'=>$this->validator->getErrors(/*associative*/ true)
                ]);
        }

        if(!empty($this->emails))
        {
            foreach($this->emails as $email)
            {
                $this->mailer->addAddress($email);
            }
            $this->compose_mail($post_data);

            if(!empty($this->attachments))
            {
                $this->attach_files();
            }

            if(!$this->mailer->send())
            {
                return json_encode([
                    'result'=>'error_sending_email',
                    'errors'=> ['mail'=> $this->mailer->ErrorInfo]
                    ]);
            }
        }

        return json_encode(['result'=>'success']);
    }

    private function validate_captcha($post)
    {
        @session_start();
        if(empty($post['captcha']))
        {
            return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code not entered']
                        ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $usercaptcha = trim($post['captcha']);

            if($_SESSION['user_phrase'] !== $usercaptcha)
            {
                return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code does not match']
                        ]);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private function attach_files()
    {

        foreach($this->attachments as $file_field)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($file_field, $_FILES))
            {
                continue;
            }
            $filename = $_FILES[$file_field]['name'];

            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($filename));

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'],
                $uploadfile))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $this->mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        }
    }

    private function compose_mail($post)
    {
        $content = "Form submission: \n\n";
        foreach($post as $name=>$value)
        {
            $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
            $content .= "$value\n\n";
        }
        $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jamie and welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help) articles - SO is NOT a tutorial side, please ask a question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Pasting a wall of code will reduce the chances of getting help. Also please be more specific about what exactly is not working. Read **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and **[how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: i have tried to word this better, hopefully it is understandable!

Comment: Read about "Decorators" pattern for styling forms. Or you can just use Zend Framework forms which are reusable. Integrate them via composer. https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form